# What to do when you know the answer to a question closed for needing more details

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

Pretty much the title: [This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/269631/manga-where-the-female-lead-is-reborn-years-later) is closed for needing more details, but I am very sure I know the manga/webtoon that is being asked for.
What do I do now?

- Comment the answer
- Comment that I know the answer
- Edit the question with additional information (seems wrong to me)
- Something else?

Comment: In this instance, I think that the question was closed unfairly, but that's not the question being asked. I voted to reopen before seeing this meta.

Comment: It has now been reopened, post that answer :)

Comment: @fez - Watch them be wrong now :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You've pretty much hit the nail on the head.

- Commenting that you think you know the answer is fine.
- Commenting *with the answer* is even better as you might get a response from OP to confirm it (in which case it's almost certainly going to get reopened and then you can convert your comment into an answer).
- [Voting to reopen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question#:%7E:text=Voting%20to%20reopen,question%2C%20not%20only%20their%20own.) is a key here (if you've got sufficient rep to earn that privilege) as it will then enter the reopen queue, to be reviewed by other users.
- Editing "correct" information into the question is a big no-no because you might be thinking of a different, but highly similar property.

You could also, as you've done, raise a meta question.

Comment: If the user feels the question is answerable, then it's reasonable for them to submit an edit to improve the question, not changes as substantial as adding supposedly "correct" information, but general improvements. When submitting the edit, they can check the checkbox below the input area which indicates that the issues are resolved. If the user can directly edit, or the suggestion is approved, then the edit being applied will push the question into the reopen queue.